# Minitube is not working? Minitube problem?

Tags: minitube

There is a app named Minitube in ubutnu software center.
It say's that it doesn't require any flash so i wanted to watch videos by it.
After installing this app i tried to open it graphically but it was not starting.
So i open up terminal and type "minitube" to open it but it gaved me following error:

```
minitube: symbol lookup error: minitube: undefined symbol: _ZNK7QLocale11uiLanguagesEv
```

Here is the result of   apt-cache policy minitube

```
minitube:
  Installed: 2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy minitube`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy libqt4-core`

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minitube
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/minitube-version-24-released-install-in.html)</sub>

This PPA is updated more frequently. Additionally you need QT 4.5 or better.